# I'm trying to install Vite from VS Studio

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install Vite from VS Studio

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/create-Vite - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'create-Vite@latest' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 This package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-15T10_18_28_420Z-debug-0.log
```

I've run the following command:

```
npm create Vite@latest --template vanilla
```

Comment: Did you even read the error? `This package name is not valid, because ... 1. name can no longer contain capital letters`

Comment: you mean VSCode?

Comment: I was so blind not to see that, But Thank you so much.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Yes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the uppercase. Check this (updated):

```
npm create vite@latest my-vanilla-app -- --template vanilla
```

`my-vanilla-app` will be your project name, and you should change the last `vanilla` to `vanilla-ts` if you want to work with TypeScript.

Comment: Ok ok, the full command should be something similar to this `npm create vite@latest my-vanilla-app -- --template vanilla` where `my-vanilla-app` will be your project name and you should change the last `vanilla` to `vanilla-ts` if you want to work with TypeScript

Comment: Check this for more info [link](https://vitejs.dev/guide/)